# Xubuntu crashes on suspend and chrome crashes often

Tags: xubuntu, google-chrome, suspend, crash

i just installed a fresh xubuntu and i am amazed of its simplicity and usability. IMHO the best OS out there.

However its crashes each time i want to suspend it. It goes gray screen and soon after the log in screen appears. If i log in then the system is weird (networks doesnt work, much doesnt work) and i have to reboot. Then it says there was an error while suspending and i should report it. I did it several times (does that even get read by anybody?).

Also my google chrome (i like it more than chromium) chrashes sometimes when i open or close a tab (it just freezes and doesnt respond at all). I have around 15-20 tabs.

AMD Phenom(tm) II X4 955 Processor (4 CPUs), ~3.2GHz
Gigabyte GA-MA770T-UD3P Mainboard
8GB RAM
ATI Radeon HD 5700 Series
Samsung SSD 840 Pro 128GB
+ several harddisks